# Сравнить ключи в списке из двух словарей Python

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть список из двух словарей.

```
USERS_LIST = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "theUser",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "James",
        "email": "john@email.com",
        "password": "12345",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "theUser123",
        "firstName": "Smith",
        "lastName": "James",
        "email": "Smith@email.com",
        "password": "12345",
    }
]
```

Необходимо проверить "id" двух словарей и если они одинаковые, то результатом будет False

Comment: Не вижу попытки самостоятельного решения этой задачи.

Comment: Мне кажется тут от другого идти нужно. Откуда у Вас вообще взялись 2 пользователя с одинаковым `Id`? Другими словами `Если Вам это понадобилось, значит Вы что-то делаете не правильно`

Answer (score 1):

```
notSame = USERS_LIST[0]["id"] != USERS_LIST[1]["id"]
```

Если id одинаковые - переменная будет False, если разные - True

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием множеств. Если все `id` одинаковые, то мощность множества == 1

```
print(len(set(x['id'] for x in USERS_LIST)) != 1)
```

```
False
```